# Prolog - Calculate the total time of a trip

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to calculate the total time I spend on a travel given the hour of departure and arrival of all places.

I'm trying to use this function only to calculate to time I'll be waiting for the next transport:

```
time_out([(_,Hf1),(Hi2,Hf2)|R],To):-
   diff_t(Hi2,Hf1,To_I),
   time_out([(Hi2,Hf2)|R],To_R),
   To is To_R + To_I.

diff_t(Hi,Hf,D):-Hf>Hi, D is Hf - Hi.
diff_t(Hi,Hf,D):-Hf=<Hi,HCA is Hf + 2400, D is HCA - Hi.
```

When I'm testing it:

```
?- time_out([(_,1300),(1400,1600)],T).
false.
```

Why doesn't it give me the total time I want?

Comment: Please, clarify, the correct answer for the example you provide is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Paulo already said, you need a base clause for the recursion:

```
time_out([_], 0).
time_out([(_, Hf1), (Hi2, Hf2)|R], To) :- 
              diff_t(Hi2, Hf1, To_I),
              time_out([(Hi2, Hf2)|R], To_R),
              To is To_R + To_I.
```

Comment: This solution is wrong, for the reason I explain in my answer: when you call the predicate with a non-empty list, you will eventually try to prove a goal with a list with a **single** element. This goal will fail, resulting in the failure of the original goal, as none of the two clauses apply.

Answer (score 1):

The `time_out/2` predicate only have a single, recursive, clause. Where's the base clause? This recursive clause is traversing the list. Assuming the predicate is called with a closed list, you eventually will be calling the predicate with an empty list as first argument. As there's no clause with an head unifying with that goal, the call fails.

Also note that your clause is not tail-recursive. I.e. there is, in this case, a goal after the **recursive** call. This means that this goal must be saved in a stack (for each recursive call) until a base case is found. This waste space (linear un the number of recursive calls). The solution to convert your predicate into a tail-recursive predicate is, in this case (and in general), to use an *accumulator* for the distance that you're computing. When you reach the (missing base case), the value of the accumulator will be the distance you're computing:

```
time_out(Stops, Distance) :-
    % the initial value of the accumulator is zero
    % as we're computing the sum of distances
    time_out(Stops, 0, Distance).

time_out([], Distance, Distance).
time_out([(_, End1), (Start2, End2)| Stops], Distance0, Distance) :- 
    diff_t(Start2, End1, Leg),
    Distance1 is Leg + Distance0,
    time_out([(Start2, End2)| Stops], Distance1, Distance).
```

But this definition is not correct. Can you spot the problem? What happens when the list contains a single start-end pair? Can you correct this definition? Maybe we have the **wrong** base case?

Most Prolog systems provide a *trace* feature, that is often helpful in understanding Prolog computations:

```
?- trace.
true.

[trace]  ?- time_out([(_,1300),(1400,1600)],T).
   Call: (7) time_out([ (_G2156, 1300), (1400, 1600)], _G2169) ? creep
   Call: (8) time_out([ (_G2156, 1300), (1400, 1600)], 0, _G2169) ? creep
   Call: (9) diff_t(1400, 1300, _G2261) ? creep
   Call: (10) 1300>1400 ? creep
   Fail: (10) 1300>1400 ? creep
   Redo: (9) diff_t(1400, 1300, _G2261) ? creep
   Call: (10) 1300=<1400 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 1300=<1400 ? creep
   Call: (10) _G2262 is 1300+2400 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 3700 is 1300+2400 ? creep
   Call: (10) _G2265 is 3700-1400 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 2300 is 3700-1400 ? creep
   Exit: (9) diff_t(1400, 1300, 2300) ? creep
   Call: (9) _G2268 is 2300+0 ? creep
   Exit: (9) 2300 is 2300+0 ? creep
   Call: (9) time_out([ (1400, 1600)], 2300, _G2169) ? creep
   Fail: (9) time_out([ (1400, 1600)], 2300, _G2169) ? creep
   Fail: (8) time_out([ (_G2156, 1300), (1400, 1600)], 0, _G2169) ? creep
   Fail: (7) time_out([ (_G2156, 1300), (1400, 1600)], _G2169) ? creep
false.
```

Look closely at call `(9)`. I will give you until tomorrow for you to find a solution to this bug. Happy hacking!

**UPDATE**

Now that the OP found a working solution is time to fix this one. For example, by writing:

```
time_out([(_, End1)| Stops], Distance) :-
    % the initial value of the accumulator is zero
    % as we're computing the sum of distances
    time_out(Stops, End1, 0, Distance).

time_out([], _, Distance, Distance).
time_out([(Start2, End2)| Stops], End1, Distance0, Distance) :- 
    diff_t(Start2, End1, Leg),
    Distance1 is Leg + Distance0,
    time_out(Stops, End2, Distance1, Distance).
```

Note that most Prolog systems implement an optimization called *first-argument indexing*, which allows trying the clauses that may be able to resolve the current goal. This optimization is usually implemented by considering the type and, for atomic terms, in some cases, the value of the first argument (if bound). The first argument in the two clauses for the `time_out/4` predicate are, for the first one, the **atom** `[]` (the empty list is **not** a list), and for the second one a **list** with one or more elements. Thus, assuming this optimization, the correct clause will be selected every time this predicate is called (with, of course, its first argument instantiated), thus avoiding spurious choice-points. The same optimization cannot, however, be applied in the case of your solution as, in both clauses for your `time_out/2` predicate, the first argument is a list.

Comment: That's progress and it works. I suggest you edit your question with the solution you found. But there's an issue with that solution: it leaves a spurious choice-point...

Comment: I think the confusion results from mixing the concept of list as a **data structure** with its **representation** using two different **Prolog term types**: an atom for the empty list an a compound term for non-empty lists. But this is not substantially different from, say, a list in C where a list is terminated by the constant `NULL`. In Prolog, the atom `[]` plays the same role as the `NULL` constant in C. I would also expect that most SO users would be able to transpose their knowledge of lists from other programming languages when learning Prolog.